# Android NullPointerException on getColor()

Tags: java, android

```
taskList.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    TextView item = (TextView) view;
                    ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) item.getBackground();
                    int colorCode = cd.getColor();
                    if(colorCode == R.color.colorGray){
                        item.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRed);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Это выплевывает NullPointerException. Мне нужно чтобы на каждом элементе ListView можно было 3 раза менять цвет.

```
12-15 20:04:40.061 23361-23361/com.igorexz.colortasks E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException 12-15 20:04:40.061 23361-23361/com.igorexz.colortasks E/AndroidRuntime
at com.igorexz.colortasks.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:42)
```

Comment: строка 42 - какая?

Comment: int colorCode = cd.getColor();

Comment: @IgorMoscalets, это значит, что `cd` у вас `null`. Что значит, что `item.getBackground()` вернуло `null`. Вопросы: назначен ли какой-то фон виджету? На какой версии андроида тестируете (уровень API)?

Comment: тестирую на 23, мин 12. виджету назначен фон из xml.

Comment: Установи цвета в файле: `res/values/colors.xml`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, проблема может заключаться в том, что вы назначаете view цвет, а получить пытаетесь drawable.

Нужно создать xml drawable и залить его нужным цветом

Полученный drawable нужно использовать в качестве фона вашего view.

Так-же нужно изменить код изменения цвета:

```
if(colorCode == getResources.getColor(R.color.colorGray, getTheme)){
   item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_drawable);
}
```